# Is it possible to add a rotate animation on an next.js image when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, image, animation, next.js

I want to add an animation to an next.js image. It should rotate by 360 degree when clicked one time. I am not able to get the desired result by trying toggle class. I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

I already tried this, but I can't get it to work:

```
<Image
src="/images/user_rotate.png"
height={20}
width={20}
alt="user_rotate"    
onClick={rotate_user}       
id="rotate_user"         
/>

function rotate_user(){
    var rotation_symbol = document.getElementById("rotate_user");
    rotation_symbol.classList.toggle("rotated");
}
```

My CSS-Module:

```
.rotated {
    animation: rotation 2s;
}

@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(32deg)
    }

    10% {
        transform: rotate(64deg)
    }

    20% {
        transform: rotate(96deg)
    }

    30% {
        transform: rotate(128deg)
    }

    40% {
        transform: rotate(160deg)
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(192deg)
    }

    60% {
        transform: rotate(224deg)
    }

    70% {
        transform: rotate(256deg)
    }

    80% {
        transform: rotate(288deg)
    }

    90% {
        transform: rotate(310deg)
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: add some code sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `event.target` will give you the object that was clicked.  Combining that with the CSS transition modifier will rotate elements smoothly.

```html
<body>
    <main>
        <button id="button" style="transition: all 0.5s; background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 50px; border: none; border-radius: 5px; color: lightblue; font-size: 18px" onclick="spin()">click me</button>
    </main>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var rotation = 0
        function spin() {
            rotation += 360;
            event.target.style.transform = "rotate(" + rotation + "deg)";
        }
    </script>
</body>
```